# Rails - Routing to seo friendly page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a site that shows twitter posts for a user. Currently when you search their name on the index page it takes you to this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/user?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=neiltyson&commit=Search
```

How would I shrink this url so it is just

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/neiltyson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit `config/routes` to use this:

```
 get "user/:username" => "user#search"
```

and then in `app/controller/users_controller.rb` :

```
 def search
    @user = User.find_by_username( params[:username] )
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) } # redirect to user#show action
    end
 end
```

Comment: `find_by` returns just 1 object, `first` will break it won't it?